# Redirect external requests to an intranet website

Tags: internet, lan

We have the following domains:

- Public domain (Internet site): mydomain.com
- Private subdomain (intranet local address): private.mydomain.com

Also, we have the following web site in our private domain:

- Private website (intranet website): private.mydomain.com/mywebsite

We want to allow connections to the intranet website "mywebsite" from the Internet (no VPN needed), keeping the rest of the intranet private (for internal users only). For example, it would be great to have this setup:

- Requests to private.domain.com (from the Internet) -> Redirect to private.mydomain.com/mywebsite
- Requests to private.domain.com/mywebsite (from the Internet) -> Allowed
- Requests to private.domain.com/anyotherwebsite (from the Internet) -> Not allowed (404)

Could you tell me how to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache this kind of thing is generally done with virtual hosts. You could restrict access to private.domain.com/mywebsite with passwords, and allow all access to private.domain.com/anyotherwebsite.

Or you could use this Apache module:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html